# Finding min value excluding zero and identifying column header

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the below formula in excel to identify the lowest value of a row of information in an excel sheet:

```
=INDEX($AK$3:$AM$3, 1, MATCH(MIN(AK63800:AM63800), AK63800:AM63800, 0)) $AK$3:$AM$3)
```

I want to exclude zeros as the lowest value.

I have tried some sources and have returned the below:

```
=INDEX($AK$3:$AM$3, 1, 
  MATCH(MIN(IF($AK$63800:$AM$63800>0, $AK$63800:$AM$63800)), 
  IF($AK$63800:$AM$63800>0, $AK$63800:$AM$63800), 0))
```

But all I get is `#VALUE!` error

I was expecting the formula to provide me with the lowest value in a row and identifying what column it was located in.

Comment: You might need to enter `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` for the second approach, if not using `MS365`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya That worked, thanks

Comment: Finding min value excluding zero: `=MIN(IF(A:A=0,"",A:A))` Replace Col A with the relevant column. For multiple columns you can change that to for example `=MIN(IF(A:D=0,"",A:D))`

Comment: Btw you can shorten your formula: `=INDEX($AK$3:$AM$3,
  MATCH(MIN((($AK$63800:$AM$63800>0)+($AK$63800:$AM$63800<>""))*$AK$63800:$AM$63800),$AK$63800:$AM$63800, 0))` but note it still needs to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while  exiting the edit mode, if you are not an `Excel 2021` or `MS365` user!

Comment: `=MATCH(MIN(IF(1:1=0,"",1:1)),1:1,0)` This will return the column number of the lowest value(excluding 0) in say ROW 1. Change as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

use MINIFS instead of MIN

```
=MINIFS(AK63800:AM63800,AK63800:AM63800,"<>0")
```

if you don`t have MINIFS in your excel
you can use AGGREGATE function

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,AK63800:AM63800 *(AK63800:AM63800/AK63800:AM63800),1)
```

the second argument in AGGREGATE is the super hero here
because it neglect the error values that's why I add the term (AK63800:AM63800/AK63800:AM63800) which will cause divided by 0 error to neglect it
so I think you full formula will be

```
=INDEX($AK$3:$AM$3,1,MATCH(MINIFS(AK63800:AM63800,AK63800:AM63800,"<>0"),AK63800:AM63800),0))
```

or

```
=INDEX($AK$3:$AM$3,1,MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,AK63800:AM63800 *(AK63800:AM63800/AK63800:AM63800),1),AK63800:AM63800),0))
```